# In Python, do I need to use close() after I use read() on a file?

Tags: python, django, memory, file-upload, file-io

I am using Django to read an ajax uploaded file to store it in a model.  The upload request contains the raw uploaded image data.

```
def my_view(request):
    upload = request
    model_instance.image_field.save(uniquename, ContentFile(upload.read()))
```

If it matters, I am using AmazonS3 as my storage backend for uploaded files.

Somewhere in the function that contains this code, I have a memory leak.

Do I need to call `upload.close()` after doing this, to free resources/memory?
Or is my memory problem coming from some other issue, elsewhere in this function?

Comment: I would have thought that AJAX would use "POST" or that Django would interpret it as a multi-part form...

Comment: Well, this is a POST request.  If I had posted the entire view you'd see that I have a check for the request method between the function definition and the relevant code.  But since it didn't seem important to the question I was asking I didn't include it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The python garbage collector will close files when they are no longer referenced.

If your `upload` variable is a local variable in a function, it'll be cleared when the function returns. Thus, the file `upload` referred to will be automatically closed during the normal garbage collection cycle.

That said, it's probably better to close the file. You can use the file as a [context manager](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.close), and it'll be automatically closed when the context is exited:

```
with open('yourfilepath.ext') as upload:
    model_instance.image_field.save(uniquename, ContentFile(upload.read()))
```

If `upload` is something Django produces for you, open and ready, you can still have it automatically closed with the [`contextlib.closing` decorator](http://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing):

```
import contextlib
with contextlib.closing(upload):
     model_instance.image_field.save(uniquename, ContentFile(upload.read()))
```

To answer the rest of your question: your leak is most likely elsewhere.

Comment: +1 for context manager - it's worth noting that although CPython's GC will close out of scope and un-referenced file objects, other implementations may not - also garbage collection is not predictable per cycle etc...

Comment: I realize that my post omitted the crucial detail of what the upload variable referred to and how it had gotten set. I made some edits to communicate that it is actually slightly different than the situation your code describes. In any event, I appreciate you taking the time to address my problem, and it's good to know that my leak is most likely elsewhere.

Comment: @ClayWardell: and my `contextlib.closing` example doesn't cover your usecase?

Comment: Yes, on second examination it does -- the part that was slightly different was your first chunk of code, and I prematurely rushed to edit and comment when I saw that.  Thanks so much!

Comment: @ClayWardell you'll probably find that your "leak" is not really a leak - it's the memory allocation system that CPython uses... it's different than the normal C `malloc` - so it may well choose that it wants to keep the memory available that was allocated for your file for something else, then decide it doesn't want it, and release back to the system again...

Comment: @JonClements that sounds possible.  My issue here is that I'm on Heroku, which allocates 512mb of memory per virtual server.  When I start using this file upload view, I go over memory on Heroku and my website starts swapping.  Even if CPython is intending on giving that memory back to me later on, I can't having our server swapping -- even if it's not a "leak," it's still using too much memory.

Comment: @ClayWardell sadly - tough luck... the Server/System will do what the heck it wants to in terms of balancing/allocating system resource. It's normally more effective to pay the provider a bit more, than spend your time, or employ someone else to do so...